# TFS 2015 Update 1 Backup success and failure alerts not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

Team Foundation Server 14.0.24712.0 (Tfs2015.Update1) backup notification alerts not working. But other notifications are working fine. When I test the email settings using "Send Test Email" feature using TFS admin console its also become successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a known issue that was fixed in TFS 2015 Update 2.

So you can upgrade to TFS 2015 Update2 or later version to fix that.

Reference this thread : [TFS backup notifications apparently not working](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eac67505-769e-4d35-a7db-95cc083fbcce/tfs-backup-notifications-apparently-not-working?forum=tfsgeneral)